# How can i generate gaussian random process using matlab?

Tags: matlab, gaussian, stochastic-process

How can i generate Gaussian random process using Matlab with zero mean and unit variance ?

Gaussian random variable can be implemented by

w=(1/sqrt(2*pi))*exp(-(t.^2)/2);

but what about Gaussian random process ?

Comment: Incidentally, that's not an implementation of a Gaussian variable, that's simply its PDF.

Comment: @Oli There is a difference between a Gaussian random variable and a Gaussian random process.  The latter has infinite dimension, it is like a function of `t` with every different `t` producing a different random variable.  @user2942448 Which Gaussian random process do you have in mind?

Comment: @StrategyThinker: Of course, and `randn` permits that.  But without further qualification, I'd interpret "Gaussian process" to mean uncorrelated Gaussian samples.

Answer (score 2):

If the Gaussian process is **white** (no correlation between samples at different instants), just use

```
w = randn(1,n);
```

where `n` is the desired number of samples.

If you need to introduce **correlation** between samples (that is, the values at different instants are correlated), the usual approach is to generate a white Gaussian process and then apply a low-pass filter (using `conv` or `filter`). The autocorrelation of the process is determined by the filter shape.

For example,

```
w = randn(1,500);
y = conv(w,ones(1,100)/10,'same'); %// apply a simple low-pass filter
plot(w)
hold on
plot(y,'r')
```

You can see that the filtered signal (red) has smoother time variations, because of the (auto)correlation introduced by the filter.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

A random Gaussian process with specified correlation length(cl) and RMSE -height(hRMSE) can be generated by passing a white noise with mean 0 and standard deviation hRMSE through a Gaussian filter `g=exp(-(x.^2)/(cl^2/2))`.

Furthermore, you can find the Matlab code under the below link: http://www.mysimlabs.com/matlab/surfgen/rsgeng1D.m

Which has been transcribed below:

```
function [f,x] = rsgeng1D(N,rL,h,cl)
%
% [f,x] = rsgeng1D(N,rL,h,cl) 
%
% generates a 1-dimensional random rough surface f(x) with N surface points. 
% The surface has a Gaussian height distribution function and a Gaussian 
% autocovariance function, where rL is the length of the surface, h is the 
% RMS height and cl is the correlation length.
%
% Input:    N   - number of surface points
%           rL  - length of surface
%           h   - rms height
%           cl  - correlation length
%
% Output:   f   - surface heights
%           x   - surface points
%
% Last updated: 2010-07-26 (David Bergström).  
%

format long;

x = linspace(-rL/2,rL/2,N);

Z = h.*randn(1,N); % uncorrelated Gaussian random rough surface distribution
                     % with mean 0 and standard deviation h

% Gaussian filter
F = exp(-x.^2/(cl^2/2));

% correlation of surface using convolution (faltung), inverse
% Fourier transform and normalizing prefactors
f = sqrt(2/sqrt(pi))*sqrt(rL/N/cl)*ifft(fft(Z).*fft(F));
```